# How do you add extra HTML elements into a Razor ActionLink

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I have this actionlink -

```
@Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", "Admin", new { url = item.thing }, new { onclick = "return confirm('Are you sure you wish to delete this link?');", new { @class = "btn btn-xs btn-danger" })
```

The class will not work with the onclick. I keep getting an error:

> "Anonymous type member".

The `onclick` will not work if there is a class. I need them to work at the same time.

How would I go about adding multiple HTML elements into an actionlink at the same time? For example - if I wanted to add inline styles or an id.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should write it like this (one object with fields not many objects):

```
@Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", "Admin", 
new {  //this is your htmlAttributes
   url = item.thing,
   onclick = "return confirm('Are you sure you wish to delete this link?');",
   @class = "btn btn-xs btn-danger"
 })
```

Answer (score 1):

With some help from Teo Van Kot's answer. This is what I've got working -

```
@Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", "Admin", new { URL = item.Thing}, new { @class = "btn btn-xs btn-danger",  onclick = "return confirm('Are you sure you wish to delete this link?');" })
```

I cannot pop URL and the @Class in the same block as it doesn't pass the URL along to my controller.

Thanks for answers. :)